# Bootstrap: Mixing buttons and input boxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/1876/), where I have a button and three input boxes and I'm using Bootstrap.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <form class='span10'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Label' id='new-row-label' class='span3'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Orders' id='new-row-orders' class='span2'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Items' id='new-row-items' class='span2'>
            <div class='btn span2' id='add-row'>Add new item</div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Two things are wrong here:

1. The button is slightly lower than the input box.
2. The button is on the *left* hand side, when in my code it appears *after* the input boxes.

How can I have three input boxes and a button, all aligned at the same height, with the button on the right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `pull-right` class with `btn` like this

```
<div class='btn pull-right span2' id='add-row'>Add new item</div>
```

it'll float the button at the right side [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/1877/) but it doesn't seems lower to me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the form classes to make an inline form:
`<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="row">
        <input type='text' placeholder='Label' id='new-row-label' class='span3'>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Orders' id='new-row-orders' class='span2'>
        <input type='text' placeholder='Items' id='new-row-items' class='span3'>
        <button type="button" class="btn" id='add-row'>Add new item</button>
    </div>
</form>`

The class="span10" on the FORM tag was also throwing off the layout.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms